# how to get html content width not window's width

Tags: javascript, html

I want to retrieve the html content width. Suppose when we resize the window to smaller size then scrollbar comes, so I want to get the width of the entire html content content that is visible and also the content the that is not visible due to the vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

```
var width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;
```

Try this code:

```
window.moveTo(0,0);
window.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);
var navButtonsEtcHeight = screen.height - window.innerHeight;
var navButtonsEtcWidth = screen.width - window.innerWidth;
```

Comment: I tried but it only gives me the width of the html content that are visible not the width of the content that are visible due to vertical scrollbar

Comment: Yes I tried, but its giving me the width of the window, not the width of the entire html content

Comment: Try with window.outerWidth and window.innerWidth

Comment: window.outerwidth is not supported by lower version of IE

Comment: Try with this code:- var divID = document.getElementById("divid");

var h = divID.style.pixelHeight;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.outerWidth` and `window.innerWidth`.

Comment: window.outerwidth is not supported by lower version of IE

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Y2a7w/)

```
<div></div>


$(function() {

  var dWth = $(document).innerWidth(),
      dHgt = $(document).innerHeight();

  $('div').append('<h2>'+dWth+'px X '+dHgt+'px</h2>');

  $(window).resize(function() {

     var dWth = $(document).innerWidth(),
         dHgt = $(document).innerHeight();

     $('div').html('<h2>'+dWth+'px X '+dHgt+'px</h2>');
  });

});
```

`$(window).width();`        // Returns width of browser viewport 
`$(document).width();` // Returns width of HTML document

Answer (score 0):

You want the Element.clientWidth property. It gives the content width of the element.

Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements